# Updating flatMap concurrent limit in the same subscription

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have an Android service that downloads files when a PublishSubject receives download events through EventBus and I want to limit the number of concurrent downloads based on a setting.

When the service is instantiated, it creates the PublishSubject and the following subscription:

```
PublishSubject<DownloadEvent> downloadsSubject = PublishSubject.create();

Subscription downloadSubscription = downloadsSubject
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .filter(event -> !isDownloaded(event))
                .flatMap(this::addDownloadToQueue)
                .flatMap(this::startDownload, preferences.getDownloadThreadsNumber())
                .onBackpressureBuffer()
                .subscribe();
```

But the setting is obtained only when the subscription is made, and changes to the setting have no effect.

Is there a way to update this value (or another approach) for next queue emissions without having to subscribe again?

Comment: I don't think this is achievable without rewriting flatMap or by overflowing flatMap via a non-conforming operator.

Comment: Oh... Then I guess I will have to resubscribe after checking if the queue is empty and the setting changed.

Comment: Why don't you limit concurrent downloads by running them on a custom Scheduler (Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n))? I assume you also want to vary n over time which could be tricky.

Comment: This is actually an interesting challenge; let me conjure up something "legal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/afc689617afbcedaa2b1) a runnable class with a custom operator which should do what you wanted.

There are several race conditions in such scenarios and I've tried to cover most of them. The operator doesn't coordinate backpressure so you may need `onBackpressureBuffer`.

Comment: It works! But is there a way to not stop threads until their work is done? They are instantly killed. I think I could add a retry() operator, but I would like to handle it here. Also, Android Studio is warning me of an error on line 201, though it compiles fine: Ambiguous method call: both 'Observable.subscribe(Observer<? super capture of ? extends R>)' and 'Observable.subscribe(Subscriber<? super capture of ? extends R>)' match

Comment: Nevermind. Your approach was already doing that. The problem was that it was getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when deleting threads. I solved it inversing the for (line 106) with: for (int i = n0 - 1; i >= n; i--). Thanks a lot!